# Laravel 4.x, CLI has stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, crash, command-line-interface

I'm using Laravel 4 based on Zend Server with PHP 5.5.

For some reason, I get the "CLI has stopped working" error every time I used the artisan serve command.
This error coming out of nowhere  when I edited my code. So I tried to reverse the code, but nothing helps.

I believe this related to the code, because other projects working well.
There's any ideas what could cause the CLI crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

It's seems that changes that I made in my SQL has directly affected on the code, and caused all those problems.